# Why the html file converted from rst file containing question mark can't displayed on browser when to click the catalog?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Please download the file `simple.7z` and install in your sphinx to reproduce issues what i described here,in order to reproduce it, you can run:

```
make clean
make html
```

[download and install in your sphinx to reproduce issues](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dprcxhy0jqm3zb3/sample.7z?dl=0)

There are two articles in `sample/source`,the content are same,only difference is the title.

```
cd  sample
ls source |grep  "for-loop"
What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop.rst
What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop?.rst
```

One contains `?` in it,the other doesn't contains `?`. 
Strange thing happend after running `make html`.

```
make html
ls build/html|grep  "for-loop"
What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop.html
What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop?.html
```

[image: please see the tile after running <code>make html</code>]
Issue 1:
Why firefox show all of then as `What does “_” in Python mean in a for-loop?`
Note:
`"_"` was combiled into `“_”` ;
The title which contain no `?` such as `What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop.html` was compiled into `What does “_” in Python mean in a for-loop?`,which add a `?` in it?

Issue 2:
To click the first title `What does “_” in Python mean in a for-loop?`,browser jump into a status `no url was not found on this server`

[image: no url was not found on this server when to click the first title]
To click the second title `What does “_” in Python mean in a for-loop?`,it works fine.
[image: works fine when to click the second title]

Please give explanation on my issue.

Comment: Please show your reStructuredText from which Sphinx generated this HTML.

Comment: `print(“Hello”)`??? You need to turn off "smart" quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issue 1** is actually not an issue, it is the normal behaviour of Sphinx: The displayed title is not the filename but the top level title of the ResT document, which is ended with a question mark in both case.
See the **Table of contents** > **.. toctree::** > **Entries** section of [this page](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#toctree-directive) which states:

> Document titles in the toctree will be automatically read from the title of the referenced document.

If you need to be convinced, just change the title of any of the document, rebuild the HTML and see.

---

**Issue 2** is caused by the presence of a non urlencoded question mark in the `href` of the link. In an url, the question mark means the start of a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

That is trying to access `What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop?.html`, means requesting the `What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop` HTML document, giving it a `.html` parameter. And obviously, the requested document is not found since it does not exist.

In the address bar of your browser, you can replace the question mark by its urlencoded form `%3F`, and observe it works then.

I did not find any way to make sphinx automatically urlencode document names in link's `href` ([it actually is considered a bug](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3097)) or any doc clearly expressing naming restriction for ResT documents.

But I know from experience that **naming a file with punctuation is often source of problems**. **I would advice you to rename your document with less exotic characters** (slugify them). Naming your ResT document `underscore_in_for_loop.rst` instead of `What does "_" in Python mean in a for-loop?.rst` will save you a lot of time and headaches.

And remember that it should not be a problem since, as we seen in the first issue, the document name is used only for the URL.

Answer (score 4):

`?` is a [wildcard](https://help.adroll.com/hc/en-us/articles/215785058-Wildcards) for part word matching in URL and hence will be treated as a special character.

wild cards operate with two type of jokers:

```
  ? - any character  (one and only one)
  * - any characters (zero or more)
```

For this, You have to [Encode the URL](https://www.urlencoder.io/python/)

```
import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote(<<url>>)
```

In Python 3.x, you need to import urllib.parse.quote:

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote(<<url>>)
```

Comment: [wildcard](https://help.adroll.com/hc/en-us/articles/215785058-Wildcards) operates with 2 jokers

Comment: I think that the `?` is treated as a wildcard and hence its not converting it to `%3f` in the URL.

Comment: It is a bug for python-sphinx then.

Comment: what is the relation between linked adroll doc and sphinx...?